# Could you describe a woman as "the apple of every man's eye in town" if she was sought after by all the men in town?

Tags: creative-writing

Suggestions for other ways to describe such a person would also be appreciated

Comment: Yes, you could, but you shouldn't.

Comment: Any better suggestions?

Comment: Use more than one sentence if you've got more than one sentence's worth of information.

Comment: This statement takes place during dialog when the characters are having an argument, so breaking it into longer sentences goes against the mood I'm trying to convey.  I'm just trying to look for a quick way for someone to claim that they (or their friend) is the most attractive person in town since they're in a fast-paced argument.

Comment: Then how about, like you just said: "[She] is the most attractive person in town" ?

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more dramatic or witty... it's supposed to be an argument after all.

Comment: She is the *Helen of Huddersfield*.  Replace *Huddersfield* with the name of the town of which she is the *Helen*.

Comment: Setting aside the show vs tell issues, "the apple of [someone's] eye" is someone you love and care for.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_of_my_eye Eg a girl is the apple of her father's eye. If all the men in town want her romantically, you need a different cliche.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I'm thinking of something like "she catches the eye of every man in town" or something along those lines.

Comment: your question is off topic for this site https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this description wouldn’t be appropriate. As Kate Gregory points out in a comment, ‘the apple of my eye’ is often used by doting parents/older relatives about children, and doesn’t work in a romantic sense.

You don’t give much context so it’s difficult to suggest a useful alternative. Any one line is going to depend on host of things, including where they are, when the story is set, the personalities involved, their relationship with each other, how they personally view the woman and what has been said in the argument so far. Knowing these things should help you write the right kind of line for your story.

A few possibilities off the top of my head that probably won't be applicable to your context, but might spark something:

‘You don’t stick a chance mate, every bloke here wants to get into her knickers.’

‘Every man here worships at her feet. What could she possibly want with you?’

‘Face it, Clifford, my daughter is more talented, better read and better looking than yours. Her suitors come from miles around.’

‘Lizzie’s sickening. She’s got all the men eating from the palm of her hand. What do I have to do to get noticed here?’

Comment: Fantastic suggestions!  Thank you

Comment: "She's got all of the men in town wrapped around her little finger" is also a good one I think

Answer (score 0):

The answer is an emphatic yes. Further you could dress that up. In fiction, you want movement and flow, emotion, oomph, a pointed description and a hold-no-punches emphasis.

*To say she was the apple of every man's eye in town was to massively, outrageously, understate the point. Clementine was far more than some common piece of fruit. She was the ship that launched. She was the summer's day. She was the drop-dead ten out of ten with a heart of gold.*

*In a word, irresistible.*

If that's too expositional for your tastes, you can modify it so that it fits dialog.

*"The apple of every man's eye? She's more than that, laddie. She's (etc)"*

Answer (score -2):

For fiction writing you need more exposition & less narrative.

Narrative tells the reader.
Exposition shows the reader.

**Narrative Example (less good)**

> George was a nice man.

**Expositional Example (more good)**

> George looked at his watch and saw it was already 7:45am. Going to be
> late for the meeting and Mr. Murphy is going to kill me. He pushed his
> front door open and ran out toward his car. As George pulled the door
> open on his Jaguar X45 he heard a faint whimpering sound.
>
> He dropped his brief case into the car and walked around to the
> passenger side and looked under the car. Nothing there. He looked at
> his watch again and felt a pulse of heat travel down his back. He
> heard the whimpering sound again and walked around to the back of his
> car and looked down at the storm drain. He held his tie back so it
> wouldn't get dirty and he looked into the drain and saw two eyes
> looking back.
>
> The small dog he was now looking at let out a louder whine and he knew
> he'd have to get it out of the drain. He reached down and was just
> able to grab the dog by the scruff of the neck and hoist him out.
>
> He pulled the dog close trying to calm it. "Hey little fella. How'd
> you get stuck down there?" He looked at his watch again. Murphy is
> going to fire me. He looked back into the puppy's eyes and said,
> "Well, I guess you can comfort me on those lonely days when I'm
> looking for my next job."

**The Challenge**
It's a lot more work to write exposition (showing the reader) than it is to just tell the reader (narrative).

You can read more about this in an answer I posted here at [Writing SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/14586/are-how-to-write-fiction-books-full-of-it/14600#14600)

Comment: Yes, but in this case the statement I'm working on is part of dialog -- the characters are arguing about who gets the most attention from the men who visit the town.  I appreciate your in-depth response, but I'd prefer if you just gave a direct answer to my question rather than trying to change my whole narrative.

Comment: "George was a nice man. That was why he never went for the eyes when torturing his victims.  Gouging someone in the eye was gross, and vicious, and George was a nice man."